# Indentation of curly brackets in functions/methods in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, indentation

Semantically speaking, does it make a difference which one of these styles you use when writing code, or will the processor parse it the same way. If there is a difference, which one is faster?

```
int function(bool) {
    ...
    return 0
}
```

or

```
int function(bool) 
{
    ...
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Yes, both of those are preferred by some people.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, really. If you are interested to specific projects, they might have their coding conventions.

Comment: Both are better than none

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct, choose one style and stick with it.

But don't use both styles in same project.

Answer (score 1):

Both styles are commonly in use. When I began programming I used the latter, it made it easier to determine that the block was closed. Now I use the former because it uses less vertical space. Both are fine.